# DBeaver SQL autocomplete issue

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Having just updated to DBeaver `22.2.4`, the autocomplete feature seems buggy & I just want to confirm I'm doing everything right before submitting a bug.

The default formatter no longer forces keywords into uppercase as I type. Instead it uppercases column, schema, and other object names! For keywords, it works if I hit `enter` (if the tooltip is visible) or `CTRL+space` (if not) after the keyword, but if I keep typing (just a `space` key), nothing changes. Properties are as follows:

- `Editors` -> `SQL Editor` -> `Code Editor` -> `Convert keyword case` is ticked.
- `Editors` -> `SQL Editor` -> `Formatting` -> `Keyword case:` is set to `Upper`.

Am I missing anything?

Tried restarting and reinstalling DBeaver a few times. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known "issue" (and intended behavior) introduced in version `22.2.4` being talked about [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/18131). A solution could be rolling back to version `22.2.3`.